# Inno setup throws error "No Files Found Matching" Even tough files are there

Tags: inno-setup

I am observing very weird behavior with inno setup whilst compiling the script.
I have following code in the script

```
[Files]
Source: "Deploy\x86\AppFiles*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: not IsX64; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
Source: "Deploy\x64\AppFiles64*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsX64; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

Even Though there are files in folder and folder location is also correct , I keep on getting error

> "No Files Found Matching"
>   Not sure what is causing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `AppFiles` and `AppFiles64` are folders, so you need this:

```
[Files]
Source: "Deploy\x86\AppFiles\*"; ...
Source: "Deploy\x64\AppFiles64\*"; ...
```

(Note the slash before `*`).

Comment: Martin, I need contents of folder

Comment: Sure, that's what my example does. Did you even try?

Comment: So did it help?